# Como saber o id da textbox criada dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com um probleminha.

Eu preciso saber qual *id* do `input type='text'` o usuário está digitando, sendo que os inputs são gerados dinamicamente. A cada novo input, é gerado uma novo id com um contador aumentando progressivamente o quanto o usuário precisa.

Por exemplo... por padrão tem apenas um campo, e quando ele aperta o botão do "+"

Surge um novo campo com ids "txtOutrosNomes1", "txtOutrosNomes2" e assim vai

Como conseguir pegar o nome desse id que foi digitado pelo usuário?

**EDIÇÃO 1**

```
 var divResponsible = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'respDiv' + contarEmails);
        divResponsible.after().html("<div id='contentEmails'><div class='row'> <div class='col-lg-12'><div class='col-lg-3'></div> <div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'><div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosNomes"+contarEmails+"'>Nome<input type='text' onclick='pegaValues()' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosNomes["+ contarEmails +"]' id='txtOutrosNomes"+ contarEmails +"' placeholder='Fulano da Silva' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'></div></div><div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'> <div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosEmails" + contarEmails+ "'>E-mail<input type='text' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosEmails[" + contarEmails + "]' id='txtOutrosEmails"+contarEmails+"' placeholder='email@email.com.br' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'></div><div class='col-lg-1'></div> </div></div> </div></div><div class='msgDados"+contarEmails+"'></div><div class='conteudo-select-partner"+contarEmails+"' style='display: none;'></div> </div>");
        divResponsible.appendTo("#groupEmails");
        contarEmails++;
```

Gero meu código dos textbox assim... como faria para adicionar as classes do bootstrap na sua solução?

Comment: Você tem ai o exemplo desse código?

Comment: do que gera dinamicamente?

Comment: Isso ... porque eu até tenho um exemplo minimo, mas, queria colocar para você bem próximo do que precisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar uma função para pegar o id do elemento [**Element.id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

e nos inputs adicionar o evento `onClick="mostraID(this)`

```js
// Element.id representa o identificador do elemento.
function mostraID(Element) {
  console.log(Element.id);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_input      = 10; //numero máximo de inputs  permitidos
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_botao      = $(".botao_add_input");
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_botao).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_input){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="t'+ x +'" onClick="mostraID(this)"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="botao_add_input">+</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="t1" onClick="mostraID(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua solução foi a mais simples e direta.. não precisei adaptar quase nada, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode gerar *listeners* dinamicamente nos `inputs` (além dos que já existem) e armazenar o `id` do último que recebeu digitação numa variável `id_input`. Sempre que quiser pegar o `id` do `input` que recebeu digitação, basta chamar essa variável.

```js
var id_input;
var conta = 1;

function geraListener(){
   var el_input = document.querySelectorAll("#conteudo input[type=text]");

   for(var x=0; x<el_input.length;x++){
      el_input[x].addEventListener('input', function(){
           id_input = this.getAttribute("id"); // retorna o ID do input
           document.getElementById("valor").innerHTML = "id do input = "+id_input; // esta linha é apenas exemplo
      });
   }

}

function addInput(){
   var novo = document.createElement("input");
   novo.setAttribute("id","txtOutrosNomes"+conta);
   novo.setAttribute("type","text");
   var div = document.querySelector("#conteudo");
   div.appendChild(novo);
   conta++;
   geraListener();
}

window.onload = geraListener;
```

```html
<div id="valor">
   vazio
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
<input id="txtOutrosNomes0" type="text" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Adicionar novo input" onclick="addInput()" />
```

### EDIT

Com jQuery seria bem mais fácil:

```js
var id_input;
var contarEmails = 1;

$("#groupEmails").on("input","input[type=text]", function(){
   id_input = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#valor").html(id_input); // esta linha é apenas exemplo
});

function addInput(){
   
   var nova_div = "<div id='contentEmails'><div class='row'> <div class='col-lg-12'><div class='col-lg-3'></div>"
   +"<div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'><div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosNomes"+contarEmails+"'>"
   +"Nome<input type='text' onclick='pegaValues()' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosNomes["+ contarEmails +"]' id='txtOutrosNomes"+ contarEmails +"' placeholder='Fulano da Silva' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'></div>"
   +"</div><div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'> <div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosEmails" + contarEmails+ "'>"
   +"E-mail<input type='text' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosEmails[" + contarEmails + "]' id='txtOutrosEmails"+contarEmails+"' placeholder='email@email.com.br' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'>"
   +"</div><div class='col-lg-1'></div> </div></div> </div></div><div class='msgDados"+contarEmails+"'></div><div class='conteudo-select-partner"+contarEmails+"' style='display: none;'></div> </div>";
   
   $("#groupEmails").append(nova_div);
   
   contarEmails++;

}

function pegaValues(){
   // fazer alguma coisa aqui
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="valor">
   vazio
</div>
<div id="groupEmails">
   <div id='contentEmails'><div class='row'> <div class='col-lg-12'><div class='col-lg-3'></div> <div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'><div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosNomes"+contarEmails+"'>Nome<input type='text' onclick='pegaValues()' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosNomes0' id='txtOutrosNomes0' placeholder='Fulano da Silva' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'></div></div><div class='col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'> <div class='form-group has-feedback' id='divOutrosEmails0'>E-mail<input type='text' class='form-control' name='txtOutrosEmails0' id='txtOutrosEmails0' placeholder='email@email.com.br' autocomplete='off' automplete='off'></div><div class='col-lg-1'></div> </div></div> </div></div><div class='msgDados0'></div><div class='conteudo-select-partner0' style='display: none;'></div> </div>
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Adicionar novo input" onclick="addInput()" />
```

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiice, vou tentar implementar essa sua solução, parece exatamente o que preciso

Comment: Cara, sua solução ta quase perfeita, só tem uma coisa...


Olha na edição que vou fazer

Comment: @gabrielfalieri Dá uma olhada na atualização da resposta. se vc usa jQuery, fica mais fácil. Poderia ter incluído a tag na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo minimo é criar um função e passar o objeto via parâmetro, no evento `KeyDown`, exemplo:

```js
function onGetId(input){
    console.log(input.id);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t1" onKeyDown="onGetId(this)" />
```

isso é um código simples ao apertar a tecla, o código te informar o `id` do objeto. No seu caso é só passar essa função na criação do objeto dinamicamente, que vai funciona da mesma forma.

Se for exemplo for criado um segundo, terceiro e assim por diante é só adicionar a função:

```
<input type="text" id="t2" onKeyDown="onGetId(this)" />
<input type="text" id="t3" onKeyDown="onGetId(this)" />
```

Um ***exemplo dinâmico***:

```js
var inc = 0;
function add()
{
  var di = document.createElement("div"); 
  var ip = document.createElement("input");   
  ip.id = "n" + inc;
  inc = inc + 1;
  ip.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
     onGetId(this);
  });
  di.appendChild(ip); 
  var ips = document.getElementById("inputs");
  ips.appendChild(di);
}

function onGetId(input){
    console.log(input.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
    
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="add()">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode percorrer os inputs de sua aplicação e pegar os ID's através do método `attr()`. ficando dessa maneira:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ipt1">
<input type="text" id="ipt2">
<input type="text" id="ipt3">
<input type="number" id="ipt4">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function(){
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
        })
    })
</script>
```

Repare que adicionei um `input` do tipo `number` só para dar um exemplo que ele será ignorado.

Answer (score -1):

Uma opção é ouvir os eventos no documento, dessa forma:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    // se o id do target contem op prefixo txtOutrosNomes
    if(e.target && e.target.id.indexOf('txtOutrosNomes') > -1 ){
       // elemento em foco
    }
 })
```

Os eventos podem ser alterados conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Gostaria de saber o motivo do downvote para poder corrigir ou alterar a resposta.

Comment: A comparação com o indexOf do nome do elemento te deixa muito amarrado, hoje temos varias opções de ter acesso aos nosso elementos, com JQuery por exemplo, é muito mais viável usar `$('input[type="text"]` que te possibilita ter acesso a todos os elementos input type text, sem saber o nome ou id. Porém não é meu o voto contra. ;)

Comment: Concordo @arllondias, nesse caso eu tambem preferiria jQuery, mas respondemos conforme a especificação na pergunta. jQuery, Angular, React, qualquer deles seria mais "facil"... e quanto ao `indexOf` também diz respeito ao problema do AP, onde somente o sufixo é alterado sendo adicionado um `id`. E em jQuery não precisaria fazer um `each` em todos os elementos, poderia usar delegate com seletores somente.

Comment: Sim sim, tem razão porém ali só usei como exemplo para percorrer os inputs mesmo para alertar como exemplo.